# How to make required field true on certain condition?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Based on input acceptance flag how to make text area required field if flag populated Yes i want to make it required if flag populated is NO not required but should be able to save the form.

HTML

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" Id="riskAcceptanceDec" 
         ng-model="processRating.riskAcceptanceFlag" 
         value="Y">Yes
  <input type="radio" Id="riskAcceptanceDec" 
         ng-model="processRating.riskAcceptanceFlag" 
         value="N">No
</div>
<div>
  <textarea class="form-control" 
            ng-model="processRating.riskAcceptanceComment" 
            name="riskAcceptanceComment" 
            required></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-required` attribute.

```
<textarea class="form-control" 
            ng-model="processRating.riskAcceptanceComment" 
            name="riskAcceptanceComment" 
            ng-required="processRating.riskAcceptanceFlag=='Y'"></textarea>
```

I know it's missing from `angular` *amazing* documentation ( there's an issue opened on github for this, which is closed  even if they didn't add directive in doc ), but you can read more about this [HERE](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1202)